# NextJS Button keeps clicking itself by React's useState

Tags: reactjs, button, next.js, use-state, react-functional-component

i'm making a comments system with nextjs and firebase, but when the page loads / the user types things inside the textbox, the button "clicks" itself and sends the current values of the textboxes to firestore

the firestore is then spammed with things like

```
h
he
hey
```

I suspect it's because of useState, but i'm not really sure what I can do

here's the parts of my code which involve the useState:

```
const submitComment = (doc, name, text) => {
    firebase.firestore().collection('blogs').doc(doc).update({ 
        comments: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
            {
                name: name,
                date: new Date().toString(),
                text: text
            }
        )
    })
} 

export default function Feedback(props) {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        liked: false,
        comment: "",
        name: ""
    })
    const toggleLike = () => setState({ ...state, liked: !state.liked })
    const commentHandler = (e) => setState({ ...state, comment: e.target.value })
    const nameHandler = (e) => setState({ ...state, name: e.target.value })

    return (
        <>
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <table className={styles.input} role="presentation">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td rowSpan="2">
                            <Textarea 
                                id="text" 
                                status="secondary" width="100%" 
                                placeholder="Comments!" 
                                onChange={commentHandler}
                            />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <Input 
                                id="name" 
                                className={styles.name} 
                                width="100%" height="100%" status="secondary" 
                                placeholder="Name" 
                                onChange={nameHandler}
                            />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <Button width="150%" type="secondary" ghost 
                                onClick={submitComment(props.post, state.comment, state.comment)}
                            >submit</Button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>           
        </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without diving too deep into context and binding `this` in javascript, the problem is in your `onClick` handler. There are a few ways to solve it, but the gist is that you need to have a function that calls your update/submit function when handling events on DOM elements.

The idea is that you're binding a function to handle the event, which will then call your function when the event happens.

One way is to create an inline anonymous function:

```js
onClick={() => submitComment(props.post, state.comment, state.comment)}
```

I personally prefer to keep this logic outside of the component body, so I'd instead move it up near the rest of your business logic:

```js
// ev is the click event
const submitComment = (ev) => {
  // You can read from state & props here
  firebase.firestore().collection('blogs').doc(props.post).update({ 
    comments: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion({
      name: state.name,
      date: new Date().toString(),
      text: state.comment
    })
  })
}

// Later...
<button onClick={ submitComment }>Submit</button>
```

---

Totally unrelated to the click issue, but also in your code you call:

```js
const toggleLike = () => setState({ ...state, liked: !state.liked })
```

I just wanted to point out that you can use the current state in your `setState` (for things like toggling likes as you are), but you should read from the previous state to ensure that you're not getting a bad value. The reason for this is that state changes are batched, not immediately fired. So you want to make sure you're reading the previous value *before* it's updated (in case anything else is updating it):

```js
const toggleLike = () => {
  setState(prevState => { ...prevState, liked: !prevState.liked })
}
```

Comment: also, thanks for the heads up on setState! I'm still getting a grasp on nextjs and react in general, so i really should learn more best practices from more experienced devs like you 

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using an anonymous callback on your button like so:

```js
onClick={() => submitComment(props.post, state.comment, state.comment)}
```